# Method that reads from keyboard(1 value parameter) or from a file(0 value parameter) doesn't work properly at 0 parameter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want my method to read triangles from keyboard or from file and then be added to `ArrayList`.. I have 2 classes: Point defined by 2 coordinates:`int c1,int c2`, and Triangle class defined by a color string and 3 points. I have 2 methods, one in `Triangle` class and one in `Point` class:

Triangle class method:

```
public Triangle readingTriangle(int value) throws Exception {
        if(value == 1) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Triangle reserve =new Triangle();
        reserve.color = sc.next();
        reserve.setA(reserve.A.readingPoint(1));
        reserve.setB(reserve.B.readingPoint(1));
        reserve.setC(reserve.C.readingPoint(1));
        return reserve;
        }
        if(value == 0) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("File"));
            Triangle reserve1 =new Triangle();

            reserve1.color=input.next();
            reserve1.setA(reserve1.A.readingPoint(0));
            reserve1.setB(reserve1.B.readingPoint(0));
            reserve1.setC(reserve1.C.readingPoint(0));
            return reserve1;
        }
        return new Triangle();


    }
```

Point class method:

```
public Point readingPoint(int value) throws Exception {
        if(value==1) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Point reserve=new Point();
        reserve.c1 = sc.nextInt();
        reserve.c2 = sc.nextInt();
        return reserve;
        }
        if(value==0) {
            Point reserve1=new Point();
            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File("File"));

            input1.next();
            reserve1.c1=input1.nextInt();
            reserve1.c2=input1.nextInt();


            return reserve1;

        }
        return new Point();

    }
```

In test class:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int triangleNumber = sc.nextInt();
    List<Triangle> triangleList = new ArrayList<Triangle>();

    for (int i = 0; i < triangleNumber; i++) {
        Triangle t = new Triangle();
        Triangle t1 = t.readingTriangle(0);
        triangleList.add(t1);

    }
    System.out.println(triangleList);
```

My output:

```
[Triangle [color=green, A=Point [c1=20, c2=20], B=Point [c1=20, c2=20], C=Point [c1=20, c2=20]]]
```

My File:

```
green
20 20
40 40
60 60
```

First, I want to mention that first piece of method is working (1 value parameter is working), I have problems with reading from file. You can see the problem from output:"20 20" is given for B and C points.

I have some things that I try to respect:

- I want my structures of methods to be, if possible, respected;
- Using Scanner is mandatory(I know it's old technique);
- I don't want to change my file, because if it was a real notepad, I don't think I will stay to change things in notepad.

Other observations:

I think the problem is at scanner methods, I tried with while(`input1.hasNext()`).

Comment: I would have your toString() and the reading method be synchronized. I would also avoid Scanner as much as possible, preferring to use BufferedReader and parsing the string myself.

Comment: If you are *required* to use Scanner, then use nextLine() and parse it yourself with the various String methods.

Comment: why do you take the number of triangles from your console while the triangles are in your file?

Comment: It is just practice,i want a method that read from keyboard or from file,depends what parameter value i put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the same instance of `Scanner`. here you are creating a new instance in each iteration in the loop, so each time it will start from the beginning of the file. So I suggest to create a single instance in main class and pass it as parameter in your methods.

Triangle class method:

```
public Triangle readingTriangle(int value, Scanner sc,Scanner input) throws Exception {
    if(value == 1) {
    Triangle reserve =new Triangle();
    reserve.color = sc.next();
    reserve.setA(reserve.A.readingPoint(1,sc,input));
    reserve.setB(reserve.B.readingPoint(1,sc,input));
    reserve.setC(reserve.C.readingPoint(1,sc,input));
    return reserve;
    }
    if(value == 0) {
        Triangle reserve1 =new Triangle();

        reserve1.color=input.next();
        reserve1.setA(reserve1.A.readingPoint(0,sc,input));
        reserve1.setB(reserve1.B.readingPoint(0,sc,input));
        reserve1.setC(reserve1.C.readingPoint(0,sc,input));
        return reserve1;
    }
    return new Triangle();


}
```

Point class method:

```
public Point readingPoint(int value, Scanner sc,Scanner input) throws Exception {
    if(value==1) {
    Point reserve=new Point();
    reserve.c1 = sc.nextInt();
    reserve.c2 = sc.nextInt();
    return reserve;
    }
    if(value==0) {
        Point reserve1=new Point();
        reserve1.c1=input.nextInt();
        reserve1.c2=input.nextInt();


        return reserve1;

    }
    return new Point();

}
```

In test class:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //the only time you create new instance of Scanner(System.in) -> for keybord input
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("File"));//the only time you create new instance of Scanner(new File("File")) -> for file input

int triangleNumber = sc.nextInt();
List<Triangle> triangleList = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
for (int i = 0; i < triangleNumber; i++) {
    Triangle t = new Triangle();
    Triangle t1 = t.readingTriangle(0,sc,input);
    triangleList.add(t1);

}
System.out.println(triangleList);
```

Comment: I appreciate a lot your effort,i think you are right,maybe I need a single instance of Scanner.I tested your method:first i modified parameters becouse it was neccesary:reserve1.setA(reserve1.A.readingPoint(0,sc,input));But it still give error:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
 at Point.readingPoint(Point.java:53)
 at Triangle.readingTriangle(Triangle.java:79)
 at Test.main(Test.java:43)   I will test your other answer too :)

Comment: i put the error in comment:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
 at Point.readingPoint(Point.java:53)
 at Triangle.readingTriangle(Triangle.java:79)
 at Test.main(Test.java:43)                                                   I like the way you solved,it is not a problem you modified parameters,only that is giving this error

Comment: in `readingPoint` method, after `Point reserve1=new Point(); `  why do you have  `input.next(); ` ? it is increasing you scanner without storing the value, I think you should remove it

Answer (score 0):

But, if you insist to not change your parameters and keep the same structure of your actual code, you can use the method of singleton, which I **do not recommend** especially if you work with threads. It works fine if you're not using threads.

So to use a single instance of `Scanner` (or any other datatype or class), you can use the design pattern "Singleton" which consist to instantiate a single instance of your Object for the whole project.

The Singleton definition for input from keyboard (a new class) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerSingletonKeyboard {
      private static Scanner sc = null;

    private ScannerSingletonKeyboard(){
        sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

    }

    public static Scanner getInstance(){
        if(sc==null)
             new ScannerSingletonKeyboard();
        return sc;

    }
}
```

The Singleton definition for input from the file (a new class) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ScannerSingletonFile {
      private static Scanner sc = null;

    private ScannerSingletonFile(){
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("File"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Scanner getInstance(){
        if(sc==null)
             new ScannerSingletonFile();
        return sc;

    }
}
```

Triangle class method:

```
public Triangle readingTriangle(int value) throws Exception {
    if(value == 1) {
        Scanner sc = ScannerSingletonKeyboard.getInstance();
        Triangle reserve =new Triangle();
        reserve.color = sc.next();
        reserve.setA(reserve.A.readingPoint(1));
        reserve.setB(reserve.B.readingPoint(1));
        reserve.setC(reserve.C.readingPoint(1));
        return reserve;
    }
    if(value == 0) {
        Triangle reserve1 =new Triangle();
        Scanner input = ScannerSingletonFile.getInstance();
        reserve1.color=input.next();
        reserve1.setA(reserve1.A.readingPoint(0));
        reserve1.setB(reserve1.B.readingPoint(0));
        reserve1.setC(reserve1.C.readingPoint(0));
        return reserve1;
    }
    return new Triangle();


}
```

Point class method:

```
public Point readingPoint(int value) throws Exception {
    if(value==1) {
        Scanner sc = ScannerSingletonKeyboard.getInstance();
        Point reserve=new Point();
        reserve.c1 = sc.nextInt();
        reserve.c2 = sc.nextInt();
        return reserve;
    }
    if(value==0) {
        Scanner input = ScannerSingletonFile.getInstance();
        Point reserve1=new Point();
        input.next();
        reserve1.c1=input.nextInt();
        reserve1.c2=input.nextInt();


        return reserve1;

    }
    return new Point();

}
```

In test class:

```
Scanner sc = ScannerSingletonKeyboard.getInstance();


int triangleNumber = sc.nextInt();
List<Triangle> triangleList = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
for (int i = 0; i < triangleNumber; i++) {
    Triangle t = new Triangle();
    Triangle t1 = t.readingTriangle(0);
    triangleList.add(t1);

}
System.out.println(triangleList);
```

and each time you want to use your scanner anywhere you only have to call `ScannerSingletonKeyboard.getInstance()` for keyboard input or `ScannerSingletonFile.getInstance()` for file inout which will return your single instance of scanner